# Expand a big product efficiently

Tags: performance-tuning, polynomials

I would like a fast way of expanding the following product:
$$\prod_{i=1}^{N_1} \prod_{j=1}^{N_2}(\partial_{z_i} - w_j) (z_i - \partial_{w_j})$$ with the rule that the derivatives are moved all the way to the left in a term before acting on the variables.

The dumb way, which one can use to check smarter attempts for small `n1,n2` is

```
{n1, n2} = {2, 3};
prod = Expand @ Product[(zder[i] - w[j]) (z[i] - wder[j]), {i, n1}, {j, n2}];

ans = prod //. {zder[i_]^e1_. z[i_]^e2_. :> D[z[i]^e2, {z[i], e1}], 
   wder[i_]^e1_. w[i_]^e2_. :> D[w[i]^e2, {w[i], e1}]} /. {zder[_] -> 0, 
  wder[_] -> 0}
```

Answers do not have to be polynomial expressions if this representation slows down the calculation. E.g. I would be fine with an answer on the form

```
ans = coeff1 * expos[{zExpoList1, wExpoList1}] + coeff2 * expos[{zExpoList2, wExpoList2}] + ...
```

where the `expoList`s are the exponents of the variables, or other formats...

There are at least two properties that I think should be exploited in order to make a fast program for this:

1. Any term with higher power of derivative than variable will vanish. These cases should be discarded as early as possible, I guess.
2. The answer is symmetric in ${z_i}$ and in ${w_j}$, i.e. `Last@SymmetricReduction[ans, Array[z,n1]] == Last@SymmetricReduction[ans, Array[w,n2]] == 0`